# Why is my console.log showing different property values if I'm using the same object?? reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, reactive-programming

Hi so here is the situation. I am building a tictactoe game with react and I have 3 components
1. GameParent
2. board
3. gameControls

I have a function inside GameParent component has two state properties called AI and Game which are objects. I pass these objects down as a prop to the board component. It also has a function called startGame()

```
startGame() {
  let newAI = new AI(this.state.AIIdentity);
  let newGame = new Game(newAI,this.state.AIIdentity);
  this.state.AI.plays(this.state.Game);
  this.state.Game.start();
  this.setState({
    start: true,
    AI: newAI,
    Game: newGame,
  });
console.log("THIS!!!",this)
console.log("THIS!!!",this.state)
console.log("THIS!!!",this)
console.log("THIS!!!",this.state.Game);
}
```

When this.state.Game.start() is called there is a property called status inside the Game object that should be changed to "running"

I pass the startGame() function down to my gameControls component and I attach it to my start button onClick handler.

My board component handles the clicks on the squares of the board but it only registers clicks if the Game.status === "running" but I keep getting the object with a status === "beginning".

So when I added these 4 console.logs, when I print out only this, I see that the Game object's status is "beginning" however when I console.log this.state and this.state.Game, the status is set to "running"!

I am so confused why this is happening... I'm guess it's the way React update it's child but I haven't found an explanation from reading how render() and setState() works. Or maybe I'm not completely understanding how "this" is affect when I pass down functions and objects to child components.

If you guys want to see the full code, here is the link
http://codepen.io/comc49/pen/WRqBXr?editors=0110

Comment: This could potentially be the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/218196 .

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not put function inside the state. State is for data only. I think that could be one source for unexpected behavior.
2. `this.setState` is an asynchronous function, that means that there is no guarantee that the state is set right after you call `this.setState`. That could explain the unexpected output from the `console.logs`